# How do I change the following query to a Zend Framework (1) query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hello I have a working query but I'm kinda new to Zend how can I change the query below to a zend query?

```
SELECT
user_dob,
user_dob + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(user_dob)) + 0 YEAR AS currbirthday
FROM user
ORDER BY CASE WHEN currbirthday < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
THEN currbirthday + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ELSE currbirthday
END
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Unrelated to Zend, it's the first time I see this kind of calculation for user's birthday.

Comment: It checks who's birthday is first according to the current time.

Comment: this is for zend framework 1 or 2?

Comment: Oh sorry for mentioning it this goes for ZF 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something Like this?, not tested,

```
$select = $sql->select ('user');

$select->columns(array(
            'user_dob',
            'currbirthday' => new Expression('user_dob + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(user_dob)) + 0 YEAR')))
->order (
    new Expression('
        CASE WHEN currbirthday < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        THEN currbirthday + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        ELSE currbirthday
        END'
    )
);
```